# is there a way to create a zip code level Geo Map in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, zipcode, geomap

I'm using the Geo Map chart in Google Data Studio. 
I'm able to plot data at the state and the city level but not at the zip code level. I'm getting a map with no data as well as the 'This map needs a valid geo dimension' error.
I've filtered all the zip codes to match `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.zipcode_area`.zipcode so it's not a data issue. I've also flagged the data as 'Postal Code' and 'Text' type but this is not resolving the issue.
Has anyone been able to plot a Geo Map at the zip code level?
I do not want to use Google Maps chart, I'd like to achieve this with the Geo Map chart.
Thanks